# $L \cong K(\sqrt{x}) \cong K[X]/(X^2-x)$ for $x \in K$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to prove that if $L$ is a quadratic extension of a field $K$ with characteristic differing from 2, then $L \cong K(\sqrt{x}) \cong K[X]/(X^2-x)$ for $x \in K$.

I tried making a isomorphism from $K(\sqrt{x})$ to $K[X]/(X^2-x)$ given that $X^2-x=0$, so $f(X)^2-f(x)=0$, by using the abc-formula I got 1 and 0. These both go to 0 in $f(X)^2-f(x)=0$, but then the function would not be bijective.

Could anyone help me with a method that should work in order to prove these isomorphisms?

Comment: Let $x$ be a number in $K$ that is not a square of an element in $K$ (that's why we avoid characteristic 2). The isomorphism $K(\sqrt{x})\simeq K(x)/(X^2-x)$ follows from the first homomorphism theorem applied to $\phi:K[X]\to K; X\mapsto x$. The isomorphism $L\simeq K(\sqrt{x})$ follows from the fact that there must be an element $y\in L;y\notin K$ and we must have  $L=K(y)$. Given the minimal polynomial $X^2+aX+b$ that $y$ satisfies, we have $(y+\frac{a}{2})^2=a^2-4b\in K$. Thus $L=K(y)=K(y+\frac{a}{2})=K(\sqrt{a^2-4b})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be a quadratic extension of $K$. Then $K(\alpha)=L$ for all $\alpha\in L\ \backslash \ K$ (because $\alpha$ is an algebraic element with degree $2$). We have to prove that exists $x\in K$ such that $L = K(\alpha) = K(\sqrt{x})$.

Take the minimum polinomial $\mu_\alpha(X) = X^2 + bX + c$ of $\alpha$. Since $char K\neq 2$ we have:
$$
\alpha = \dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}
$$
Then $K(\alpha)=K(\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}) = K(\sqrt{\Delta})$. Take $\Delta=x$ and you are done.

The last isomorphism is given by the evaluation map:
\begin{gather}
K[X]\longrightarrow K[\sqrt{x}]\\
X \longmapsto \sqrt{x}
\end{gather}
That is surjective and the kernel is $(X^2 - x)$ that is maximal because $x$ is not a square in $K$.

Comment: What do you mean by $K(\alpha)=L$ for all $\alpha \in L \setminus K$? Why does that follow from $\alpha$ being algebraic with degree 2?

Comment: @mathstudent Take an $\alpha\in L$ but $\alpha \notin K$. You have $K(\alpha)\subset L$.

$[K(\alpha):K]\leq 2$ because $[L:K]=2$.

Since $\alpha\notin K$ then $[K(\alpha):K]\neq 1$. 

So $[K(\alpha):K]=2$ and now you have an inclusion and the equality of the degrees, so $K(\alpha)=L$

Answer (score -1):

You map $\sqrt{x}\longmapsto X$, and there is no other element of $K(\sqrt{x})$ which maps to $X$, so your mapping is bijective.

Comment: But why is it important that the characteristic differs by 2? I don't seem to understand where we use that.

Comment: @mathstudent the mapping is injective iff $\sqrt{x}\notin K$. If $\text{char}(K)=2$, this may be impossible: e.g., consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$. On these field the Frobenius endomorphism $x\mapsto x^2$ is an automorphism, i.e. every element of $K$ is a square.

Comment: Let us assume $\operatorname{char}K=2$. Then $x^2-y^2=(x-y)^2$ and if $x$ and $y$ are different, so are their squares. Hence we have as many elements in $K$ as we have squares in $K$. But if every element is a square, then $K(\sqrt{x})=K$.